# Visible feedback on ToolButton press

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qml

I added a ToolButton in the QML of my application. But while the associated action is performed, the toolbutton does not react visibly when clicked.

[image]

```
ToolButton {
    action: Action {
        text: qsTr("Run")
        iconSource: "qrc:/icons/arrow487.svg"
        onTriggered: {
            aboutApplicationDialog.open()
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to have a visible feedback on the button, similar to the feedback a checkable ToolButton provides:

[image]

```
ToolButton {
   iconSource: "qrc:/icons/bookmarks.svg"
    action: Action {
        checkable: true
    }
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: This works for me with Qt 5.2.1 and 5.3 on Windows 7. What's your Qt version?

Comment: @Mitch Qt 5.2.1 on OSX 10.9.